Evaluating a generalised integral: $I(n)=\int_0^1\frac{x^n\ln^2(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{x^2\ln^2(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$$
I started with the substitution $x^2=t\implies 2x\,dx=dt\implies \,dx=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\,dt \implies [0,1]\to[0,1]$
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{t\ln^2(\sqrt{t})}{\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}}\,dt$$
$t=\sin^2 \theta\implies dt=2\sin \theta \cos \theta\,d\theta\implies [0,1]\to\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$
$$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sin^2 \theta \ln^2(\sin \theta)}\,d\theta$$
Now, on searching on similar integrals, I used beta function and double differentiated it to evaluate $I$ $$I=\frac{\pi\log^2(2)}{4}-\frac{\pi\log(2)}{4}+\frac{\pi^3}{48}-\frac\pi8$$
This matches the answer, however I am interested in how we can extend this integral and generalize it for any $n>0$
$$I(n)=\int_0^1\frac{x^n\ln^2(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$$

Mathematica says
$$I(n)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\cdot \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) \left(\left(H_{\frac{n-1}{2}}-H_{\frac{n}{2}}\right){}^2+\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)-\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)\right)}{8 \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)},\ n>-1$$
$H_n$ gives the $n^{th}$ harmonic number.
$\psi^{(n)}(z)$ gives the $n^{th}$ derivative of the digamma function.

or: $$\frac{2 , _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1+n}{2},\frac{1+n}{2},\frac{1+n}{2};\frac{3+n}{2},\frac{3+n}{2},\frac{3+n}{2};1\right)}{(1+n)^3}$$

Interesting is the asymptotic $$I_n=\frac{3 \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}}{4 n^{5/2}}\Bigg(1-\frac{5}{4 n}+\frac{35}{96 n^2}+\frac{105}{128 n^3}+ O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\Bigg)$$

@ClaudeLeibovici indeed

Partial integration yields
$$
I(n) = x^n \frac{\log x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x[\log x-1]\mid_0^1
-
\int_0^1 dx x[\log x-1]
[nx^{n-1}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
+x^{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
+x^{n+1}\frac{\log x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}
]
$$
Assume that $n\ge 1$ such that the first term on the RHS vanishes:
$$
I(n) =
-
\int_0^1 dx
[
nx^n\frac{\log^2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
+(1-n)x^n\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
-x^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
+x^{n+2}\frac{\log^2x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}
-x^{n+2}\frac{\log x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}
]
$$
$$
=
-nI(n)
+\int_0^1 dx
[
(n-1)x^n\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
+x^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
-x^{n+2}\frac{\log^2x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}
+x^{n+2}\frac{\log x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}
]
$$
Define $J(n)=\int_0^1 x^n/\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$, $K(n)=\int_0^1 x^n\log(x)/\sqrt{1-x^2}$,
$L(n) = \int_0^1 x^n\log(x)/(1-x^2)^{3/2}$,
$M(n) = \int_0^1 x^n\log^2 (x)/(1-x^2)^{3/2}$
so
$$
(1+n)I(n)= (n-1)K(n) +J(n) -M(n+2) +L(n+2).
$$
By the substitution $x=\sin(t)$, $dx=\cos(t) dt$
$$
J(n) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^n(t) dt = 2^{n-1}B(\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{n+1}{2})
$$
where $B(x,y)=\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)/\Gamma(x+y)$ is the beta-function.
For even and odd $n$ we have the integrals 4.241.1 and 4.241.2 in the Gradsteyn-Ryzhik tables
in terms of double factorials and harmonic numbers,
$$
K(2n)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n}\log x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx
= \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\frac{\pi}{2}[\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{(-)^{k-1}}{k}-\ln 2];
$$
$$
K(2n+1)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n+1}\log x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx
= \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}[\ln 2 + \sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \frac{(-)^k}{k}].
$$
Recursively
$$
L(0)=-\frac{\pi}{2};\quad L(1)=-\ln 2;
$$
$$
L(n+2)=\int_0^1 x^2 \frac{x^n\log x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}
$$
$$
=\int_0^1 (x^2-1) \frac{x^n\log x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}
+\int_0^1 \frac{x^n\log x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}
$$
$$
=-\int_0^1 (1-x^2) \frac{x^n\log x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}
+\int_0^1 \frac{x^n\log x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}
$$
$$
=-\int_0^1 \frac{x^n\log x}{(1-x^2)^{1/2}}
+\int_0^1 \frac{x^n\log x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}
$$
$$
=-K(n) +L(n).
$$
Recursively
$$
M(n+2)=\int_0^1 x^2 \frac{x^n\log^2 x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}
$$
$$
=\int_0^1 (x^2-1) \frac{x^n\log^2 x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}
+\int_0^1 \frac{x^n\log^2 x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}
$$
$$
=-\int_0^1 (1-x^2) \frac{x^n\log^2 x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}
+\int_0^1 \frac{x^n\log^2 x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}
$$
$$
=-\int_0^1 \frac{x^n\log^2 x}{(1-x^2)^{1/2}}
+\int_0^1 \frac{x^n\log^2 x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}
$$
$$
=-I(n) +M(n).
$$
$$
M(0) = \int_0^1 \frac{\log^2 x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}dx = \pi \log 2\approx 2.17758609\ldots
$$
$$
M(1) = \int_0^1 x\frac{\log^2 x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}dx = \frac{\pi^2}{12}-\log^2 2\approx 0.3420140\ldots
$$
Insertion into the recurrence for $I(n)$ yields
$$
(1+n)I(n)=
(n-1)K(n)
+J(n)
-[M(n)-I(n)]
+L(n)-K(n).
$$
$$
nI(n)=(n-2)K(n)+J(n)-M(n)+L(n).
$$
and all terms on the right hand side are known.
For more general integrals of that kind see https://arxiv.org/abs/2408.15212 .

In $K(2n)$ and $K(2n+1)$ is that $(-1)^k$(apologies i could not find Gradsteyn-Ryzhik tables reference online to verify) , also this is an interesting answer

$(-)^n$ is always $(-1)^n$, a very common notation (at least decades ago). AFAIK the GR tables are not online anywhere, but the integrals are already in the "Nouvelles tables d'integrals d'definies" by D. Bierens de Haan of 1867 , reprinted 1939, Table 118 (page 168 of the reprint).

That notation was new to me, also found the book here - http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/~svincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf

Suppose we have a function $\mathrm{J(n)}$
$$J(n) = \int^{1}_{0}{\dfrac{x^n}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}dx$$
let $x = \sin(\theta) , dx = \cos(\theta) d\theta$
$$\int^{1}_{0}{\dfrac{x^n}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}dx = \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\sin^n(\theta)d\theta$$
Gamma Function
$$\int^1_{0}x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1} = \dfrac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$$
let $x = \sin^2(t) \text{  thus  } dx = 2\sin(t)\cos(t) dt$
$$2\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}{\sin^{2a-1}(t)*\cos^{2b-1}(t)}dt=\int^1_{0}x^{b-1}(1-x)^{a-1} = \dfrac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$$
In previous case we have $n = 2a-1$ , $2b-1 = 0$
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\dfrac{\Gamma(\dfrac{n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\dfrac{n+2}{2})}=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\Gamma(\dfrac{n+1}{2})*\Gamma(\dfrac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\dfrac{n+2}{2})}=\int^{1}_{0}{\dfrac{x^n}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}dx$$
derivate wrt $n$ twice using Leibniz , we got $I(n)$ .Therefore just need to find $$\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\dfrac{d^2}{dn^2}\left(\dfrac{\Gamma(\dfrac{n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\dfrac{n+2}{2})}\right)$$
Now finish with , $\Gamma'(n) = \psi(n)*\Gamma(n)$ and quotient rule
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=D%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bgamma%5C%2840%29Divide%5B%5C%2840%29n%2B1%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%2Cgamma%5C%2840%29Divide%5B%5C%2840%29n%2B2%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%5D%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bn%2C2%7D%5D
Wanted to see this kind of answer more .U may follow me in instagram by
https://www.instagram.com/willsonmathclass/

Isn't it  $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\sin^n(\theta)d\theta$

Also Isn't it $\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\dfrac{n+1}{2})}{2\Gamma(\dfrac{n+2}{2})}=\int^{1}_{0}{\dfrac{x^n}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}dx$

But I sort of see where this answer is headed, thanks for the idea!

Yes u are correct, i misplaced the cos

hope this answer help

Yes sir, this does help, also good work on the instagram page!

Thanks @whatamidoing
